# Dynamic logo in community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder

I have question. 
I trying build custom layout for my napili community but In different communiy I need different logo.

Could I get this logo via attribute or something else ?

[image]

I added logo to the communities and try this code but steel I don't have logo ...

```
public static Map<String,String> getBranding() {
    Map<String,String> branding =  new Map<String,String>();
    Id communityId = Network.getNetworkId();
    List<CustomBrand> CustomBrandId = [ select id from CustomBrand where ParentId =: communityId Limit 1];
    for(CustomBrandAsset asset : [select id, AssetCategory, CustomBrandId, TextAsset from CustomBrandAsset where CustomBrandId =: CustomBrandId[0].Id]) {
        branding.put(asset.AssetCategory,asset.TextAsset);
    }
    return branding;
}
```

and my output is JSON

```
"objectBranding" : {
    "MotifZeronaryColor" : "#51606E",
    "MotifPrimaryColor" : "#1797C0",
    "MotifSecondaryColor" : "#51606E",
    "MotifTertiaryColor" : "#DDE4E9",
    "MotifQuaternaryColor" : "#B1BAC1",
    "MotifZeronaryComplementColor" : "#FFFFFF",
    "MotifPrimaryComplementColor" : "#FFFFFF",
    "MotifTertiaryComplementColor" : "#222222",
    "MotifQuaternaryComplementColor" : "#222222"
  }
```

Comment: If you have 2 different communities why can't you just upload the logos for each one separately from Community Builder?

Comment: 2 communities is just only example if you need can be 99 communities where we should use one layout with different communities:) 

I need display image from this branding to the my custom layout. I know that this is posible but I can't find solution for it yet.

Comment: I know that it is possible to use a Lightning Component for the layout which can be reused in different communities with the image stored in a static resource and pulled in to the template from their rather than in each community. I don't have access to the code for this at the moment, so I can't post a proper answer till later, but it is possible.

Comment: @JJanek with a minimum effort, you should be able to right click on the image from a community and fetch the url path from an uploaded resource....I encourage you to try.

Comment: I don't know if I correct undestood you :)
I as developer can hardcode it or using static resource. But I prepare this for people who will manage communities - they are only use community builder branding to define all - font, colors, logos.

Comment: I trying force solutions base on, attachement, assets in site studio com, static resource but I must use logo from branding ;)

Comment: In that case, this question has already been asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/142138/accessing-header-image-and-other-values-from-custom-themelayout)

Comment: gll - question maybe been asked but answer is not for me;) 
In standard layout we do not have to define a name to use logo and header.

Comment: Were you able to get this working?

Comment: @glls - I added answear below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution without apex.

To display logo on my component when I use napili community template  should add below code to lightning component:

```
<div class="capricornThemeLayout siteforceNapiliBody" aura:id="baseThemeForm">
  <div class="capricornContainer">
    <div class="capricornNavBar">
      <div class="cBrandingLogo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The company logo and backgrounds are images stored in the assets library. 
[image]

You should be able to easily fetch them using Apex and in return expose them using a design file either in a custom theme layout or a component or reference them directly using an attribute as a background or logo in your component.

[image]
[image]

So, yes, this is possible. you just need to code the solution.

Comment: Actualy I found path to the standard objects like;CustomBrand  and CustomBrandAsset and I know that there are stored my pictures ;) 

So when I coded this I put answear : )

Comment: I believe those are only applicable for Salesforce1

Comment: Hm, I updated my question with code and output ... I don't know what i did wrong.

Comment: CustomBrand and CustomBrandAsset are for Salesforce1, not Lightning communities